# New line in Expression language

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, jstl

```
  ${result.comments}
```

the above expression language  contains too much text

**Current Output**

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzzz

**Expected output**

abcdefghijk

lmnopqrstuv

wxyzzzzzzzz

zzzzzzzzzzz

zzzzzzzzzzz

zzzzzzz

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use CSS to style those long texts. The property you might be interested in is `word-break`. Here's an example:

```
.comment {
    word-break: break-all;
}
```

For more details check out this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_word-break.asp).